# How to add free shipping over dollar amount functionality to "Local Pickup" in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

We are using "Local Pickup" for local delivery on our website with a $10 charge. I would like to allow orders over $75 to be delivered for free, but the only way I know to do that is through a coupon, and I need it to happen dynamically. I bought a few plugins, but neither could achieve this. Am I missing something really simple? Or is there a bit of code that could be added to the functions.php document that would achieve this? Right now orders can ship anywhere, and local residents can have their items delivered. Not sure if I'm overthinking this. Thanks in advance! L. Hawk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce comes with a free shipping method integrated.

There you can find a minimum order amount option, that you can set to $75.

[WooCommerce's official documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/free-shipping/) explains its setup process step by step.

The only "tricky" part is to find and click the `Edit` option right below the method's title `Free shipping`.
At the next screen you can configure the shipping method accordingly.